# actualizar modelo mediante un reduce

Tags: javascript, nodejs, mongodb, mongoose

Hola disculpen mis erropres estoy comenzando, tengo una "lista" que es un arreglo json, de donde necesito actualizar un modelo llamdo "User" con algunos parametros presentes en el codigo, pero me da error y se que es la estructura del codigo, pero no consigo la manera si pudiesen ayudarme agradecido:

```
async function actualizarProceso(lista) {


  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {

    lista.reduce(function(previous, elemento) {
      console.log('elemento', elemento.previo.pasarela)

      var result = User.findOneAndUpdate({
          "_id": lista._id
        }, {
          $set: {
            "pasarela": elemento.previo.pasarela,
            "fecha_fin": elemento.previo.fecha_fin,
            "dispositivos": elemento.previo.dispositivos,
            "estado_token": elemento.previo.estado_token
          }
        },

      )

    }, 0);
    resolve(result);
  });

}
```

si Riven era un de los errores, lo modifique pero me marca este error

este es el error que me envia:
 result is not defined, pero no se como sacar y hacer el resolve, al colocar el resolve dentro del reduce no hace la actualizacion....

Comment: Podrias poner el error que te trae, aunque cabe mencionar que en tu pregunta se te escapo el corchete final de la función, pero no creo que sea eso, seguro se te habrá olvidado copiarlo cuando copiaste el código a la pregunta.

Comment: gracias @Riven por tu tiempo y dedicacion

Comment: Tienes una clase llamada User y esta clase tiene un metodo statico llamado findAndModify?

Comment: es un modelo de BD, y si el modifique el metodo pero me arroja este error ahora :(

Comment: Podrías agregar parte de esa clase?, no toda, pero sí por ejemplo la clase y el metodo findOneAndUpdate dentro de ella.

Comment: cual es el proposito de usar `reduce`? Si puedes explicar un poco mas osea que resultado esperas

Comment: el reduce es para iterar la lista que me trae un arreglo de varios elemntos en un jason...

Comment: @Riven es una funcion propia de mongoDB

Comment: Ejecutas ese código en nodejs cierto??

Comment: si em nodejs y en la bd mongo

Answer (score 0):

**PROBLEMA**

Tu problema es de [asincronía](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Asincron%C3%ADa). Ya que en tu función reductora, haces el llamado a un método asíncrono: `findOneAndUpdate()` de Mongoose.

El método [`reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Array/reduce) no es asíncrono y por lo tanto no esperará por el resultado de cada llamado a `findOneAndUpdate`.

Podemos ver este ejemplo:

```js
const lista = [1, 2, 3, 4]

const reductorSync = (acumulador, valorActual) => {
  console.log(`acc: ${acumulador}, cur: ${valorActual}`);
  return acumulador + valorActual;
}

const reductor = (acumulador, valorActual) => {
  console.log(`acc: ${acumulador}, cur: ${valorActual}`);
  //emulamos un proceso asíncrono con un Timeout
  return setTimeout(() => {
    console.log(acumulador + valorActual);
    return acumulador + valorActual;
  }, 0);
}

console.log(`Resultado Sync: ${lista.reduce(reductorSync)}`);

console.log(`Resultado Async: ${lista.reduce(reductor)}`);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

¿Qué sucedió? Simplemente la operación de reducción en el caso asíncrono se llevo a cabo en un momento diferente al esperado. Y eso es lo que sucede con tu código.

Otro problema que veo en tu código es que tu función reductora devuelve el resultado de una actualización sobre un documento de una colección. No sé el porqué querrías usar específicamente `reduce()` para llevar a cabo la tarea, cuando podrías hacerlo con cualquier otro método tal vez más apropiado, por ejemplo: [`forEach()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Array/forEach).

Por último, de lo que puedo deducir del código que has expuesto, lo que deseas hacer es actualizar diferentes documentos de la colección de usuarios con valores que se encuentran en la lista que recibe tu función como argumento. Dices que la lista es un arreglo o `array` de objetos. Pero tienes esta línea:

```
"_id": lista._id
```

Evidentemente `lista._id` será siempre `undefined`, ya que un tipo `Array` no posee dicha propiedad o atributo. Así que, *asumiendo* que te refieres al campo `_id` de cada objeto de tu lista, lo correcto sería:

```
"_id": elemento._id
```

o tal vez:

```
"_id": elemento.previo._id
```

dependerá de la estructura de tus objetos.

**SOLUCIÓN**

Si tengo una lista de objetos que tienen los valores a actualizar en la colección de usuarios, debemos hallar una forma iterativa de actualizar todos los documentos afectados con los valores presentes en la lista.

Ninguno de los métodos de los tipo `Array` nos sirven para este propósito, ya que no son asíncronos.

Una posible solución es usar [`Promise.all()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Promise/all).

Supongamos que la estructura de cada objeto en la lista es la siguiente:

```js
[
  {
    _id: <ObjectId>,
    previo: {
      pasarela: <String>,
      fecha_fin: <Date>,
      dispositivos: <Array>,
      estado_token: <String>
    }
  },
  { ... },
  ...
  { ... }
]
```

Podemos observar que cada elemento de la lista es un objeto con 2 campos: `_id` y `previo`, y este último es el que contiene los valores a actualizar en nuestro documento.

Dado que buscaremos documentos por el campo `_id` que es único para cada documento, en vez de usar `findOneAndUpdate` usaremos directamente [`findByIdAndUpdate()`](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.findByIdAndUpdate).

La consulta quedaría escrita de la siguiente forma:

```js
User.findByIdAndUpdate(
  element._id, 
  { $set: {
    pasarela: element.previo.pasarela,
    fecha_fin: element.previo.fecha_fin,
    dispositivos: element.previo.dispositivos,
    estado_token: element.previo.estado_token
    }
  },
  { new: true }) // <- esto devuelve el documento actualizado
                 // si no lo estableces, devolverá el documento encontrado
                 // antes de la actualización, y pensarás que no se actualizó
```

Ahora necesitamos construir un `iterable` cuyos elementos sean promesas. De la [documentación](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/queries.html#queries-are-not-promises) de Mongoose sabemos que las consultas o *Queries* no son Promesas, por lo tanto debemos envolver la misma dentro de una Promesa.

Por ejemplo:

```js
const updatedUser = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  User.findByIdAndUpdate(...)
  .then(user => {
    console.log('User updated.');
    resolve(user);
  })
  .catch(error => {
    console.error(error.message);
    reject(error);
  });
});
```

Hasta aquí se parece un poco a lo que ya tenías implementado. Pero necesitamos una forma de que cada `updatedUser` sea parte de un iterable, y además debemos asegurarnos que cada uno de ellos se actualiza de acuerdo a los elementos de la lista.

De entre los métodos del tipo `Array` que podríamos usar para recorrer la lista, vamos a escoger [`map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Array/map), ya que el mismo se adapta a lo que necesitamos, es decir, crea un nuevo `Array` (entiéndase iterable) con el resultado de la función `callback` que le pasamos como argumento, y dicha función recibe a su vez entre sus argumentos el elemento de la lista que estamos iterando.

Podríamos escribir lo siguiente:

```js
lista.map(element => {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    const update = { 
      $set: {
        pasarela = element.previo.pasarela,
        fecha_fin = element.previo.fecha_fin,
        dispositivos = element.previo.dispositivos,
        estado_token = element.previo.estado_token
      }
    };
    User.findByIdAndUpdate(element._id, update, {new: true})
    .then(user => {
      console.log('User updated.');
      resolve(user);
    })
    .catch(error => {
      console.error(error.message);
      reject(error);
    });
  });
});
```

Muy bien, con esto, `lista.map()` representa un iterable de promesas, podemos pasar este iterable como argumento de `Promise.all()`.

Cabe destacar que `Promise.all()` devuelve una promesa, por lo tanto no hace falta declarar tu función como tipo `async`.

Tu método finalmente podría quedar parecido al siguiente:

```js
function actualizarProceso(lista) {
  return Promise.all(lista.map(element => {
    const update = {
      $set: {
        pasarela = element.previo.pasarela,
        fecha_fin = element.previo.fecha_fin,
        dispositivos = element.previo.dispositivos,
        estado_token = element.previo.estado_token
      }
    };
    User.findByIdAndUpdate(element._id, update, {new: true})
    .then(resolve); // <= Gracias a la programación funcional
    })
    .catch(reject); // <= Gracias a la programación funcional
    });
  }));
}
```

Ahora sólo debes usar tu función `actualizarProceso()` bien con `then()` y `catch()`, por ejemplo:

```js
// ...

actualizarProceso(lista)
  .then((updatedUsers) => {
    console.log(updatedUsers);
    //...
  })
  .catch(console.error); // <= Gracias a la programación funcional.
```

O bien dentro de una función tipo `async` con `await`:

```js
// dentro de una función o método async puedo usar await, siempre dentro de un
// bloque try catch

try {
  const updatedUsers = await actualizarProceso(lista);
  console.log(updatedUsers);
  // ...
} catch (error) {
  console.error(error.message);
  //...
}
```

Espero que con esto aclares las dudas sobre cómo realizar la actualización de elementos de una lista con NodeJS y Mongoose.